# How to write a JSON object to a file to later be read in JuliaLang?

Tags: json, io, julia

I am using this package from JuliaIO to work with JSONs; https://github.com/JuliaIO/JSON.jl

Creating some sample JSONs appears straightforward;

```
dict1=Dict();dict1[1]=[1,2,3];dict=Dict();dict["1"]=dict1;
```

and then creating a JSON from this key-value structure;

```
import JSON
jDict1 = JSON.json(dict)
```

and now I want to save it to disk so that I can read it in the future;

```
JSON.print(open("t1.json","w"),jDict1)
```

The command does not report any error, and a file name "t1.json" is created in the local folder, but it is empty with 0 bytes. How should I be writing the JSONs to file?

The documentation in the README.md mentions the IO, but I seem to be missing the concept of what and `IO` is referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File's data are cached. You need to flush them. (close function is flushing too).

You could do

```
f = open("t1.json","w")
JSON.print(f,jDict1) 
close(f)  # or flush(f)
```

or you could use [do block syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1)

```
open("t1.json","w") do f
    JSON.print(f,jDict1) 
end
```